# How to add an EsLint Constraint for next/link

Tags: html, next.js, eslint, eslintrc

I want to display a linting error if the  component from next/link is used.

The only routing allowed should come from the defualt .

I've added the "@next/next/no-html-link-for-pages": "off" statement to eslint rules, it only allows the use of  tag and solved this error.

12:9 Error: Do not use the HTML tag to navigate to /. Use Link from 'next/link' instead. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-html-link-for-pages @next/next/no-html-link-for-pages

In place of this, it does not display eslint errors on the terminal if the  component is used.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: That lint rule is there to enforce `next/link` usage in Next.js, it's not meant to do the opposite. You'll have to create your own rule to display errors if `next/link` is used. That being said, it's not recommend to disable the `@next/next/no-html-link-for-pages`, as you'll be losing client-side navigations capabilities the `next/link` and the Next.js router provide.

Answer (score 0):

That warning message wants you to use `next/link` instead of `<a>`. In your code, you might have this to navigate to a new page

```
      <a  href="/">
          ........
      </a>
```

Using `<a/>` causes unnecessary full-page refreshes which affects on the performance of your app. Instead

```
<Link href="/"> 
  <a>
    ....
  </a>
</Link>
```